# Azure Blob Upload without container name - Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am able to upload a blob (BlockBlob) to a container and to sub-directories using the below code:

```
String storageConnectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";      
CloudStorageAccount account;
CloudBlobClient serviceClient;
CloudBlobContainer container;
CloudBlockBlob blob;

account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("sample");
container.createIfNotExist();

blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("myfolder/test/31-Mar/testing/testvideo.wvm");
File fileReference = new File("C:\\myvideo.wvm");
blob.upload(new FileInputStream(fileReference), fileReference.length());
```

How do I upload in case I do not have the container name and I have only the container reference?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I have only the container reference.`? Since a blob is always uploaded into a container, you would need to have access to that container somehow.

Comment: I mean the container name isn't available but the path to where the blob has to be uploaded is available

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: Say,I have a file myvideo.wvm and it need to be uploaded to "myfolder/test/31-Mar/testing/testvideo.wvm" path in azure blob storage.

Comment: Blobs are **always** uploaded in a container. In your case, `myfolder` would be the container which must be present before the blob can be uploaded.

Comment: I thought so and confirmed it from the storage explorer.           Thanks a lot Gaurav !!

Comment: One more thing, the security level of the container is changing from Public to private when I upload a blob into it. Why is this happening.

Comment: In which container are you uploading the files?

Comment: A container with public level security, when I upload blob to it, its security level is changing to private